# How to sync as much as possible to one directory, then the rest to another (on Windows)

Tags: windows, sync

I'm trying to sync as much as possible (memory allowing) to a device's internal memory, and then sync the rest to the SD card the device is using.

By sync I don't just mean copy, I mean an rsync-style copy that skips copying files that are already there and identical.

Is this possible at all without explicitly dividing the files I want to sync into two parts, one of which will fit into the internal memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many programs that will do this for you.  Robocopy, CopyHandleer, Richcopy, or just a good old fashion batchfile.

Batchfile would be my preferred method.  You can use the archive bit to mark the files you've already copied.

Then run the copy command again, copying the ones with the archive bit still on to the SD card.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this is possible in the context of an embedded device such as you are asking about.  It should be possible on systems where you have more control over the file system.

For example, I believe NTFS on windows supports spanning physical volumes in the same folder, such that it will fill up one first, but it would be a real pain to set up.

Comment: I'm realizing that anyway it's stupid to want to do this when the internal memory size is fixed.
I can just set aside that portion of data to sync to the internal memory, which also avoids changing what's in the internal memory and what's in the card everytime new files are created that are towards the beginning in alphabetical order.
How about just syncing in the first place then? It seems the cygwin-based rsync implementations have a hard time handling special characters in filenames. Does robocopy do what I want?